# stanforddependencies module python win32error

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, permissions

I'm trying to make the StanfordDependencies module work, but there seems to be an error in the code when I try to parse a tree from text that results in a WinError 32 notice from the SubprocessBackend.py file. Here's code for attempting to use the module:

```
import StanfordDependencies
sd = StanfordDependencies.get_instance(backend='subprocess')
sent = sd.convert_tree('(S1 (NP (DT some) (JJ blue) (NN moose)))')
```

And here's what's debugged:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\StanfordDependencies\SubprocessBackend.py", line 111, in convert_tree
    return self.convert_trees([ptb_tree], **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\StanfordDependencies\SubprocessBackend.py", line 87, in convert_trees
    os.remove(input_file.name)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\new\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpldetf3e5'
```

Following this, I'm posting the code from the SubprocessBackend file included in the module where the issue arises (the last line is line 87):

```
self._raise_on_bad_representation(representation)
        input_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        try:
            for ptb_tree in ptb_trees:
                self._raise_on_bad_input(ptb_tree)
                tree_with_line_break = ptb_tree + "\n"
                input_file.write(tree_with_line_break.encode("utf-8"))
            input_file.flush()

            command = [self.java_command,
                       '-ea',
                       '-cp', self.jar_filename,
                       JAVA_CLASS_NAME,
                       '-' + representation,
                       '-treeFile', input_file.name]
            # if we're including erased, we want to include punctuation
            # since otherwise we won't know what SD considers punctuation
            if include_punct or include_erased:
                command.append('-keepPunct')
            if not universal:
                command.append('-originalDependencies')
            if debug:
                print('Command:', ' '.join(command))
            sd_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                          universal_newlines=True)
            return_code = sd_process.wait()
            stderr = sd_process.stderr.read()
            stdout = sd_process.stdout.read()

            if debug:
                print("stdout: {%s}" % stdout)
                print("stderr: {%s}" % stderr)
                print('Exit code:', return_code)

            self._raise_on_bad_exit_or_output(return_code, stderr)
        finally:
            os.remove(input_file.name)
```

Is there some code I should add somewhere before this last command that will close the file, or is there a better approach to take?